# background-image header media queries

Tags: html, css, header, media-queries, background-image

I'm looking to change the background image in the header of my small web project and adapt it responsively. I tried to put a class="header_accueil" in my header to differentiate the different sections of the site but it doesn't work. I have also looked on other forums but still haven't found anything that could help me.

Here is my css code and my html code:

```css
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    .header_accueil { 
        background: url('images/4585760.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        display:block;
        }
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Site</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header_accueil">

    </header>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is my folder where all my files are stored:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJBUR.png)

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The snippet does not show anything because no height has been given to the element.

Answer (score 0):

I change my html code and my css code :

```css
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 480px) {

    .header_accueil {
    
    background: url('images/4585760.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    display:block;
    height: 1000px;
    
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 1224px){
    body{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Site</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header_accueil">
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
    </header>

</body>
</html>
```

but nothing has changed.